# Приведение JSON модели к Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Возникла проблема, при тестировании методов *restAPI*.

Необходимо производить валидацию модели, полученной в результате выполнения запроса и эталонной модели. Я похоже изобретаю жуткий велосипед, но идея была такова, что бы преобразовать json модель типа: `{ "key0" : "value", "key1" : "value", ... , "key_n" : "value" }` к словарю, и сравнить значения у полей.

Чувствую, что либо так не делают, либо есть подход проще. Если кто нибудь сталкивался или знает куда копать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Для начала странная у вас json модель. Обычно она выглядит как то так `{ key:value,key2:value2}`. Вы написали, что вам нужна валидация полей. Т.е. не структура json, а именно наличие нужных полей (не значений), так?

Comment: Простите, я пока писал, о чем то другом задумался похоже, {"key":"value"}, нужно проверить и наличие полей, и данные, которые они содержат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть на JSON.net [тык](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Дело в том, что ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы десериализовать полученный json и проверить данные. Есть несколько способов.

1. Сделать класс Class1, который будет содержать нужные поля. И
   потом десериализовать с помощью `Class1 variable =
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(json)` ; Ну а как проверить переменную класса на значения думаю не так уж и сложно.Чаще всего будет проще словить на моменте сериализации т.к. там сразу же будет ошибка при попытке сериализовать не тот тип или отсуствующее поле.
2. [Тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php) описано, как можно упростить процесс, описанный выше с помощью DataContractJsonSerializer.
3. Работать с json как с обычным объектом. Т.е. десериализовать строку в объект и потом проверять наличие полей (keys) и значений по этим полям. Но я бы не рекомендовал это т.к. это дольше, сложнее и т.п.);

Можно еще посмотреть [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread603816.html). Возможно это наведет вас на нужную мысль.

UPD [Как сериализовать в WEb API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

Comment: Напоминаю, что в ASP.NET WebApi за десериализацию json отвечает MediaTypeFormatter, а не пользовательский код.

Comment: @PavelMayorov но я же написал про JSON.net. Да, это подключаемый модуль и все такое. Но он достаточно просто все делает. С MediaTypeFormatter нужно чуть больше понимания что и как. Хотя я с вами согласен - возможно в первую очередь нужно указать вариант с коробочным вариантом